# how can i hide long text from center with dot (eg: Like myfile...n.jpg)

Tags: css

How to limit text shown with using “…” I want to trim some text from center.

Original Text are : digital document.pdf

Convert it into : digital...t.pdf

Reference site is 
http://compresspng.com/

Comment: are you open to use jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Css Solution.**

I have used simple `data-attribute` with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to achieve the effect you need.

> Here is the snippet:

```css
#Dname {
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
}

#Dname p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Dname:after {
  content: attr(data-filetype);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Dname" data-filetype="t.pdf">
  <p>digital document.pdf</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for MIGHT be the css property called `ellipse` in text-overflow.

### Example

```
.example {
    width: 10em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
<span class="example">This is my file name</span><span>.extention</span>
```

What the above example does is it creates a block of width 10em and lets text of upto that size to be displayed as is and then adds `...` to it.

Comment: But OP wants some character from end too. Your answer will not do such thing. :)

Comment: I did add *might* to the answer. And we could always break the words in two pieces. Getting file extension via js is not a big deal ;)

Comment: Agree. But Using CSS `ellipsis` is only way I think and OP didn't specified that he is flexible with JS too. :)

Comment: Well. I don't know any better way. And the point here is that this is more of a guide that he is looking for not an exact solution. If he doesn't want answers involving scripts then he will have to find some other way for the same.

Answer (score 0):

ES5

```
var string = 'digital document.pdf'

var shortenedString = string.substr(0, 7) + '...' + string.substring(string.length-5)
```

ES6

```
const string = 'digital document.pdf'

const shortenedString = `${string.substr(0, 7)}...${string.substring(string.length-5)}`
```

Yes, I know the answer is JS and not CSS. But it will do what is required and you can just display the shortened string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with trimming the string and add ... at the end you can use css like :

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

If you want like filenameStart...fileEnd.fileExtention then you can do it using javascript :

```
var file = 'testLnongName123456789123456789142.pdf';

var fileData = file.split(".");

// you can add the length check you want, i have added 10 for reference

if(fileData[0].length > 10){
    file = fileData[0].substring(1, 4) + '...' + fileData[0].slice(-4) + '.' + fileData[1]; 
}
console.log(file);
```